# Link against libnfc on a windows machine

Tags: c#, dll, nfc

I'm successfully using libnfc with GNU/Linux and C/C++. Now I need to write a *bridge* library under Windows, so I can easily access libnfc with C#. In short sentence:
I'm not able to link against the *libnfc.dll*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libnfc_read_only\include\nfc\nfc.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << nfc_version() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

C:\Users\peter\nfc_access>x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o test test.cpp -Llibnfc_build\libnfc -llibnfc

```
C:\Users\peter\nfc_access>x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o test test.cpp -Llibnfc_build\libnfc -llibnfc
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skippi
ng incompatible libnfc_build\libnfc/libnfc.dll.a when searching for -llibnfc
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skippi
ng incompatible libnfc_build\libnfc/libnfc.dll when searching for -llibnfc
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skippi
ng incompatible libnfc_build\libnfc/libnfc.dll.a when searching for -llibnfc
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skippi
ng incompatible libnfc_build\libnfc/libnfc.dll when searching for -llibnfc
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot
 find -llibnfc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The same happens, when I try to link my dll against this.

```
C:\Users\peter\nfc_access>file libnfc_build/libnfc/libnfc.*
libnfc_build/libnfc/libnfc.dll;   PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
libnfc_build/libnfc/libnfc.dll.a; current ar archive
```

What Im doing wrong?

// edit
C:\Users\peter\nfc_access>file bar_dll.dll lib_bar_dll.a
bar_dll.dll;   PE32+ executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Mono/.Net assembly
lib_bar_dll.a; current ar archive

I can't link against this dll! But what does "Mono/.Net" mean in this context? This is native code!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
C:\Users\peter\nfc_access>g++ -o touchatag_bridge.dll touchatag_bridge.cpp -Wl,--out-implib,touchata
g_bridge.a -Llibnfc_build\libnfc -llibnfc -m32 -shared
Creating library file: touchatag_bridge.a
```

The option *-m32* solved it - horray!